# Binding to property in code behind through window name

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, binding

I would like to bind a textbox to a property of the window that is defined in the code behind file.

The binding succeeds when referencing the window when setting a RelativeSource using "FindAncestor" to find the window.

Why does it not work to reference the window by its name, just like I can bind the window's "Title" property?

**XAML:**

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication123.MainWindow"
        x:Name="MyWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="WPF Binding Example" Height="180" Width="237">
<Grid>
    <TextBox Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="24,24,0,0" Name="textBox1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="136"
             Text="{Binding ElementName=MyWindow, Path=Title}"/>
    <TextBox Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="24,53,0,0" Name="textBox2" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="136"
             Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}}, Path=XYZ}"/>
    <TextBox Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="24,82,0,0" Name="textBox3" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="136"
             Text="{Binding ElementName=MyWindow, Path=XYZ}" />
  </Grid>
</Window>
```

**Code behind:**

```
namespace WpfApplication123
{
  public partial class MainWindow : Window
  {
    public MainWindow()
    {
      InitializeComponent();
      XYZ = "XYZ!";
    }

    public string XYZ { get; set; }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just set this.DataContext = this and then bind to path.

You need

```
XYZ = "XYZ";
```

before the InitializeComponent

when the textbox is initialized XYZ is null

Comment: The crucial point was in fact that WPF takes the value of the property during IntializeComponent(). At that time, the property was not yet set. Thanks for making that clear! Setting the DataContext in the window class is just an alternative to using ElementName in XAML.

Answer (score 1):

I never used a normal property, but my guess is you need to implement the INotifyPropertyChanged interface, and raise the property changed event in the setter of XYZ.
The imho better approach is to use a dependency property directly.

Just make XYZ a dependency property and it should work.

Comment: A dependency property or implementing INotifyPropertyChanged is not necessary in my simple example as I'm focussing on the initial state (just when the window is first displayed). Using FindAncestor takes place after constructing the window object, so at that time, my property was set and the value was displayed in the textbox. Thanks though for your feedback!